# Coupled differential equations: Laplace transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

> By using Laplace transforms find the steady state values of w, u and v:$$\frac{du}{dt}=-\frac{\Gamma}{2}u+\Delta v,$$$$\frac{dv}{dt}=-\frac{\Gamma}{2}v - \Delta u +w \Omega,$$$$\frac{dw}{dt}=-\Gamma-\Gamma w - \Omega v.$$ Where $\Gamma, \Omega,$ and $\Delta$ are constants, and $v(t), u(t),$ and $w(t)$ are functions.

**Attempt:**

So these DEs are in fact a form of Maxwell–Bloch equations. To find the steady state, I set all the time derivatives equal to zero on the LHS. Then I took the Laplace transform of both sides:

$$L \{-\frac{\Gamma}{2}u+\Delta v\}= \frac{- \Gamma}{2} U(s)+\Delta V(s) =0 \tag{1}$$

$$L \{-\frac{\Gamma}{2}v - \Delta u +w \Omega \}= \frac{- \Gamma}{2} V(s)-\Delta U(s)+ \Omega W(s) =0 \tag{2}$$

$$L \{-\Gamma-\Gamma w - \Omega v \}= -\frac{\Gamma}{s} - \Gamma W(s) - \Omega V(s) \tag{3}=0.$$

So what would be the steady state values? How do we proceed from here?

And can we assume that $s=0$ lies in the region of convergence?

Comment: Similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123441/using-the-laplace-transform-to-evaluate-the-steady-state-of-a-function

Comment: Ah, thank you for the link. So basically for the steady states of $v(t), u(t),$ and $w(t),$ we want $$\lim_{s \to 0} s V(s), \lim_{s \to 0} s U(s), \lim_{s \to 0} s W(s).$$Is that right? So to find expressions for the Laplace transform of each of these, we must solve the three equations in my post above for three unknowns? Are my Laplace transform expressions above correct?

Comment: Yes, but you do not set the all three time derivatives equal to zero; instead you have to take Laplace transform of the full coupled ODEs, solve for $V(s), U(s), W(s)$. Then you evaluate the limit as stated above.

Comment: Why do you solve that with Laplace ? Setting the LHS equal to zero gives an easy linear system.

Comment: What do you mean by taking the Laplace transform of "the full coupled ODEs"? We need to set them to zero in order to be able to solve them simultaneously. For example in **(1)** and **(3)** I wrote both $U(s)$ and $W(s)$ in terms of $V(s),$ then by using **(2)** I found:$$V(s)=\frac{-\Gamma}{s\left( \frac{\Gamma}{2}+ \frac{2\Delta^2}{\Gamma}+ \frac{\Omega}{\Gamma} \right)}.$$Then we need to evaluate $$\lim_{s \to 0} s \frac{-\Gamma}{s\left( \frac{\Gamma}{2}+ \frac{2\Delta^2}{\Gamma}+ \frac{\Omega}{\Gamma} \right)}$$But I am not sure why the limit doesn't look right.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The question specifically asks to use the Laplace transform approach.

Comment: Your approach by cancelling the derivative then taking the Laplace transform is wrong. You must keep the derivative terms, solve for the unknown functions and apply the final value theorem.

Answer (score 4):

Using a vector notation, the system reads

$$\frac{d\mathbf x}{dt}=A\mathbf x+\mathbf b.$$

Take the Laplace transform, giving

$$s\mathbf X-\mathbf x_0=A\mathbf X+\frac{\mathbf b}s,$$ solved by

$$\mathbf X=(sI-A)^{-1}\left(\mathbf x_0+\frac{\mathbf b}s\right).$$

To get the response at infinity, multiply by $s$ ant take the limit at $0$,

$$\mathbf x_\infty=\lim_{s\to0}s\mathbf X=\lim_{s\to0}\,(sI-A)^{-1}\left(s\mathbf x_0+\mathbf b\right)=-A^{-1}\mathbf b.$$

---

This is obviously the solution of the steady-state system

$$0=A\mathbf x+\mathbf b.$$

Using the Laplace transform is overkill for this problem.

Comment: You should have $\lim_{s \to 0}$ after the second equation in the last line before the break. Also, it can happen that the Laplace transform of $x$ doesn't even exist for all $Re(s)>0$, that depends on the eigenvalues of $A$ and possibly on $x_0$. Without noticing this one would find that every linear system with constant coefficients approaches a steady state, which is obviously nonsense.

Comment: @Ian: right, I fixed the typo. Indeed all of this only makes sense for a stable system. (Anyway, a system exactly in the steady state remains in the steady state, even unstable.)