# Steady-state of a system and Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I successfully found the Fourier Transform of a function $f(t)$. Suppose the Fourier transform looks like the one below, so its not easy to calculate the Inverse transform:

### $$ F(w) = a ^{c - \sqrt{b -2\cdot i\cdot \omega}} $$

How do I obtain or analyze the "steady-state" of this system? Either $\frac{df}{dt}=0$ or $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) $?

Note that the FT that I wrote above is a simplified version of the one I am dealing with, and I have not been able to find the inverse FT of my function, so I prefer to analyze the steady-state using the Fourier transform, rather than reverting the transformation.

Comment: If you compute $F(\omega)$ as the Fourier transform of $f(t)$, then by the Fourier inversion theorem the inverse transform of $F(\omega)$ is $f(t)$. Could you tell us what $f(t)$ is exactly? Also, its not clear to me what exactly you are trying to do with the Fourier transform of $f(t)$ if you are trying to find the steady state of $f(t)$..

Comment: @Mattos thank you. The Fourier inverse of my function is not easy to compute, so I am trying to analyze the Fourier transform for its steady state rather than explicitly finding the inverse transform.

Comment: @Mattos I am going off this notion that the Fourier transform is, or is closely related to, the steady state of a function $f(t)$. See for example, this post on the physics forum: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/fourier-transform-and-steady-state-solution.253337/  and also this post on math exchange : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/123441/using-the-laplace-transform-to-evaluate-the-steady-state-of-a-function

Comment: What exactly is $F$ and what are the assumptions on the parameters? If the Fourier integral of $f$ exists and $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t)$ also exists, the limit has to be zero.

Comment: Hello @Maxim , $F$ is the outcome of trying to solve an integral equation and is as above, where $a>0$, $b>0$, and $c>0$. Am I completely misguided thinking that we can obtain the "steady-state" based on the FT, or that these concepts are somehow related?

Comment: They are certainly related. If we know that $f(t) = \int_{\mathbb R} F(\omega) e^{-i t \omega} d\omega$, we can apply asymptotic analysis techniques to the integral to determine how fast $f$ decays at infinity. But your $F$ is a Schwartz function, this already implies that $f$ tends to zero faster than any power function. I'm assuming that we in fact have $a > 1$ (your $F$ can be reduced to $e^{-k \sqrt {1 + i \omega}}$, and we need $k > 0$).

Comment: @Maxim thank you for your help, I wish I had asked about a function that is not Schwartz so I could have a better idea about how to go about exploring the steady-state.

Comment: @Maxim is there then no statement like the "final value theorem" for the Fourier transform as there is for the Laplace transform? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_value_theorem  In the case of Laplace, $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) = \lim_{s \to 0} s\cdot F(s)$

Comment: @Maxim for example, would it be valid under some circumstances to make the change of variables $w = s/i$ and then take evaluate $\lim_{s \to 0} sF(s)?$