# "Steady-state" of Error function using Fourier Transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am interested in studying the steady state dynamics of a function, by means of looking at the Fourier transform. As a way to illustrate, suppose that the signal I want to study is the error function. In the problem I must solve, the function is slightly more complicated, but perhaps the intuition with the error function might help me enough.

We know that if $ f(t) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^t e^{-x^2}dx$, then,

$$ F(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) \cdot e^{i\cdot\omega\cdot t} dt = \frac{i}{\omega} e^{-\frac{\omega^2}{4}}\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}.$$

Just based on the Fourier transform, I would like to be able to make conclusions about the long-term behavior $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)$. This is, because the function that I am studying does not seem to be easily invertible. Yet, we know in the case of the error function that:

$$\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^x e^{-t^2}dt = 1$$

When only the Fourier transform is available, is there a way to look at the following limit:

$$ \lim_{t\to\infty}f(t) = \lim_{t\to\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty F(\omega) \cdot e^{-i\cdot\omega\cdot t} dw = ?? = 1 $$

(Disclosure: I asked a similar question before here [Steady-state of a system and Fourier Transform](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330975/steady-state-of-a-system-and-fourier-transform?noredirect=1#comment6855203_3330975), however, based on the comments I received, I thought it would be better to start with a new clearer, post. Thanks to Mattos and Maxim. I can delete the old one, if its necessary)

Comment: The Fourier integral of $f$ doesn't exist (we've already established that it cannot exist for any $f$ s.t. $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) = 1$). What you have is the FT of a distribution. It still might make sense to consider the growth of the regular part of a distribution.

What is true in terms of ordinary functions is
$$f(t) = \operatorname{v.\!p.} \int_{\mathbb R}
\frac {i e^{-p^2/4 - i t p}} {\pi p} dp.$$
If $t > 0$, the integral is equal to $1$ (from the residue at zero) plus the integral over $\operatorname{Im} p = - 1$. The latter is $e^{-t}$ times the FT of a Schwartz function.

Comment: @Maxim thank you.. I think I should probably study this a bit better. I have one more explicit question about calculating one FT for which I get an answer on Mathematica, but I am not quite sure how to solve it by hand.